# Enviar imagen a Email con mail() php

Tags: php, laravel, imagen, email

Cuando envío un email hacia un correo, no se ve la imagen. Y cuando inspecciono el elemento me dice que tiene esta url:

```
<img style="display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto" src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/G_k4sW8WuFm52fEoztbRyL1LgS5wBSR9mXL25C5DlsYilkFfnQ=s0-d-e1-ft#http://img/img.jpg" class="CToWUd">
```

Y yo lo que envío es ésto:

```
<img style='display:block;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;' src='www.worknow-cursos.com/img/img.jpg' /></div>
```

Eh leído que google tiene un proxy propio para proteccion de imagenes pero no logo encontrar la solución. Acá dejo el mail:

```html
$to = "Usuario <" . $user->email . ">";
        $subject = "Resolucion de trabajo practico para $user->name ";

        $message = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body style='font-family: 'arial';'>

<div style='width: 100%;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;background: #ffbb38; border-radius: 18px;display:block; float:center;'><h2 style='padding: 15px;color:#b22222; font-weight: bold; text-align: center'>INSTITUTO WORK NOW</h2> </div>
<p style='text-align: center; color: #4b5665; line-height: 21px; font-size: 18px;'><span style='font-size: 24px;'>Hola! C&oacute;mo estás?</span> <br>
¡Felicidades! tu trabajo pr&aacute;ctico est&aacute; aprobado </p>
<div style=''><img style='display:block;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;' src='www.worknow-cursos.com/img/img.jpg' /></div>
<p style='text-align: center; color: #4b5665; line-height: 21px; font-size: 18px;'>Cuando lo desees podes solicitar mas actividades.</p>
<div >
<table style='display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;' class='m_-3791644720194112676m_-5077930976808664309gmail-m_-7832111776023786876m_-1983291102630745082gmail-rnb-del-min-width m_-3791644720194112676m_-5077930976808664309gmail-m_-7832111776023786876m_-1983291102630745082gmail-rnb-tmpl-width' width='100%' cellpadding='0' border='0' cellspacing='0' bgcolor='#f9fafc' name='Layout_' id='m_-3791644720194112676m_-5077930976808664309gmail-m_-7832111776023786876m_-1983291102630745082gmail-Layout_' style='min-width:590px;width:590px'><tbody><tr><td class='m_-3791644720194112676m_-5077930976808664309gmail-m_-7832111776023786876m_-1983291102630745082gmail-rnb-del-min-width' align='center' valign='top' bgcolor='#f9fafc' style='border-collapse:collapse;min-width:590px'><table width='590' class='m_-3791644720194112676m_-5077930976808664309gmail-m_-7832111776023786876m_-1983291102630745082gmail-rnb-container' cellpadding='0' border='0' align='center' cellspacing='0'><tbody><tr><td height='20' style='border-collapse:collapse;font-size:1px;line-height:1px'>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td valign='top' class='m_-3791644720194112676m_-5077930976808664309gmail-m_-7832111776023786876m_-1983291102630745082gmail-rnb-container-padding' align='left' style='border-collapse:collapse;font-size:14px;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:rgb(136,136,136)'><table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='m_-3791644720194112676m_-5077930976808664309gmail-m_-7832111776023786876m_-1983291102630745082gmail-rnb-columns-container'><tbody><tr><td class='m_-3791644720194112676m_-5077930976808664309gmail-m_-7832111776023786876m_-1983291102630745082gmail-rnb-force-col' valign='top' style='border-collapse:collapse;padding-right:20px;padding-left:20px'><table border='0' valign='top' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='264' align='left' class='m_-3791644720194112676m_-5077930976808664309gmail-m_-7832111776023786876m_-1983291102630745082gmail-rnb-col-2' style='border-bottom:0px'><tbody><tr><td valign='top' style='border-collapse:collapse'><table cellpadding='0' border='0' align='left' cellspacing='0' class='m_-3791644720194112676m_-5077930976808664309gmail-m_-7832111776023786876m_-1983291102630745082gmail-rnb-btn-col-content'><tbody><tr><td valign='middle' align='left' class='m_-3791644720194112676m_-5077930976808664309gmail-m_-7832111776023786876m_-1983291102630745082gmail-rnb-text-center' style='border-collapse:collapse;font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif'><div><div>Work Now Cursos<br>11 2694 2226<br>MDQ, CP7600<br>CABA, CP1428<br><a href='https://my.sendinblue.com/camp/showpreview/id/27#' style='color:rgb(102,102,102)' target='_blank' data-saferedirecturl='https://www.google.com/url?q=https://my.sendinblue.com/camp/showpreview/id/27%23&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1548339436236000&amp;usg=AFQjCNE2hiKhyGADz7Y2axjhkSAJmCyG-g'>alumnos@worknowcursos.com</a></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td><td class='m_-3791644720194112676m_-5077930976808664309gmail-m_-7832111776023786876m_-1983291102630745082gmail-rnb-force-col m_-3791644720194112676m_-5077930976808664309gmail-m_-7832111776023786876m_-1983291102630745082gmail-rnb-social-width' valign='top' style='border-collapse:collapse;padding-right:15px'><table border='0' valign='top' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='246' align='right' class='m_-3791644720194112676m_-5077930976808664309gmail-m_-7832111776023786876m_-1983291102630745082gmail-rnb-last-col-2'><tbody><tr><td valign='top' style='border-collapse:collapse'><table cellpadding='0' border='0' cellspacing='0' class='m_-3791644720194112676m_-5077930976808664309gmail-m_-7832111776023786876m_-1983291102630745082gmail-rnb-social-align' align='right' style='float:right'><tbody><tr><td valign='middle' class='m_-3791644720194112676m_-5077930976808664309gmail-m_-7832111776023786876m_-1983291102630745082gmail-rnb-text-center' width='85' align='right" style="border-collapse:collapse"><div class="m_-3791644720194112676m_-5077930976808664309gmail-m_-7832111776023786876m_-1983291102630745082gmail-rnb-social-center"><table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="float:left;display:inline-block"><tbody><tr><td align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse;padding:0px 5px 5px 0px"><span style="color:rgb(255,255,255)"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/WorkNowarg/" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.facebook.com/WorkNowarg/&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1548339436236000&amp;usg=AFQjCNFFJjZzil1R7uXNXjZ-kRaC0MziWw"><img alt="Facebook" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" src="https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/lSkv6A04VUKQTkRddYrPg7o-Bxzozl9Bnl7XN-mOrPTzj4Ob7cz30iOTkj1vi9pDIWO79R2VHrfWCTtJHIVLVweWPw1H5v1qF4PkbXI44wvL=s0-d-e1-ft#http://img.mailinblue.com/new_images/rnb/theme5/rnb_ico_fb.png" style="vertical-align:top" class="CToWUd"></a></span></td></tr></tbody></table></div><div class="m_-3791644720194112676m_-5077930976808664309gmail-m_-7832111776023786876m_-1983291102630745082gmail-rnb-social-center"><table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="float:left;display:inline-block"><tbody><tr><td align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse;padding:0px 5px 5px 0px"><span style="color:rgb(255,255,255)"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/worknowarg/" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.instagram.com/worknowarg/&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1548339436236000&amp;usg=AFQjCNGfqWATRlLhzVpEf4J_BEAzLPjAQw"><img alt="Instagram" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" src="https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/cUFg0Ysnzaor5bg_lrB83LzjqQ_6OvYzqQOIyy27-K-CpmcJljVWiMxNEFx-TLweor4hVeMQgjibDkDMuY7TdG6HsSHdGypnKXcc0OxbYdFE=s0-d-e1-ft#http://img.mailinblue.com/new_images/rnb/theme5/rnb_ico_ig.png" style="vertical-align:top" class="CToWUd"></a></span></td></tr></tbody></table></div></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr><td height="20" style="border-collapse:collapse;font-size:1px;line-height:1px">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></div>

</body>
</html>

        ";

        ini_set("SMTP", "smtp.gmail.com");
        ini_set("sendmail_from", "alumnos@worknowcursos.com");
        ini_set("smtp_port", "465");
        // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

        // More headers
        $headers .= 'From: <alumnos@worknowcursos.com>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Cc: alumnos@worknowcursos.com' . "\r\n";

        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Aclaro el email se envía perfectamente, pero la imagen no se muestra.

Comment: porque no agregas toda la ruta:....http://www.worknow-cursos.com/img/img.jpg

Comment: te falta el "http://"

Comment: Ya lo pruebo y te digo

Comment: Agrega `http` o `https` según el caso: `src='http://www.worknow-cursos.com/img/img.jpg'`

Comment: Era el http. Increíble como no darse cuenta. Gracias !

Comment: @DiegoAvila lo vio primero, le toca a él escribir una respuesta y llevarse unos cuantos puntos :)  Me alegro de que se haya resuelto de ese modo. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo unico que te faltaria agregar es la ruta absoluta sea **http://** ó **https://**
en tu caso la ruta quedaria algo asi:

```
http://www.worknow-cursos.com/img/img.jpg
```

en tu codigo seria:

```
<img style='display:block;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;' src='http://www.worknow-cursos.com/img/img.jpg' />
```

suerte..!!

Comment: Gracias Diego ! solucionado !